# Validação FlaskForm com Flask - Falha no form.validate_on_submit()

Tags: python, flask

Boa tarde pessoal, tudo bem?
Criei um formulário utilizando a classe FlaskForm, do flask_wtf. Consigo enviá-lo para o front da aplicação e aparentemente o comportamento está correto.
Porém, quando vou submetê-lo para fazer a validação, acabo não conseguindo "cair" no bloco da mesma. O comportamento que eu esperaria em app.py, ao fazer o preenchimento e submeter os dados seria de cair no regForm.validate_on_submit() e assim dar um redirect para a home. Porém, estou "caindo" na outra condição (print "we are here 2") e renderização do template admin-register (vide código app.py abaixo). Alguém poderia me ajudar por favor? Não encontro o erro já busquei de diversas formas.
Estou utilizando as seguintes versões das tecnologias:

Python 3.7.4 ; email-validator==1.1.2 ; Flask==1.1.2 ; Flask-Assets==2.0 ; Flask-WTF==0.14.3 ; WTForms==2.3.3

**Retorno ao submeter o formulário**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Arquivo app.py**

```
from flask import Flask,flash, jsonify, request, render_template, url_for, redirect
from flask_assets import Environment, Bundle
from authforms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
import json, secrets
from os import environ

########   APP START   ########

#initialize the app
app = Flask(__name__)

#routes - Web
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    homeTitle = 'O melhor buscador de CID'
    return render_template('index.html', title=homeTitle)

#routes - Web (Admin)
@app.route('/cadastro-admin', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def admin_register():
    regForm = RegistrationForm(request.form)
    if regForm.validate_on_submit():
        flash(f'Conta criada para {regForm.adminName.data} :)', 'message_success')
        return redirect(url_for('home'))
    registerTitle = "Cadastro para administradores do sistema de buscas inteligentes de CID"
    print("we are here 2")
    return render_template('admin-register.html', title=registerTitle, form=regForm)

#run the application
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**Arquivo authforms.py (classe responsável pelos formulários de registro e login):**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import Form, StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField, validators
from wtforms.validators import Email, Length, DataRequired, EqualTo
import email_validator

class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
    adminName = StringField('Nome', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=30)], render_kw={'placeholder': 'Nome:'})
    adminSurname = StringField('Sobrenome', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=3, max=30)], render_kw={'placeholder': 'Sobrenome:'})
    adminEmail = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()],render_kw={'placeholder': 'E-mail:'})
    adminPass = PasswordField('Senha', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=6, max = 20)], render_kw={'placeholder': 'Senha:'})
    confirmPass = PasswordField('Confirme a Senha', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')], render_kw={'placeholder': 'Confirmação da senha:'})
    submit = SubmitField('Cadastrar')
```

**Arquivo html aonde o formulário está sendo renderizado**

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% block content %}
<header>
  <h1>Será um administrador do sistema? Cadastre-se aqui</h1>
</header>

<article>
  <form method="POST" action="" name="admin_register_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{form.hidden_tag()}}

    {%if form.adminName.errors%}
      {{form.adminName(class="registration_form_input")}}
      <div style="display:block; border: 1px solid red">
        {%for error in form.adminName.errors%}
          <span>{{error}}</span>
        {%endfor%}
      </div>
    {%else%}
      {{form.adminName(class="registration_form_input")}}
    {%endif%}
    
    {{form.adminSurname(class="registration_form_input")}}
    {{form.adminEmail(class="registration_form_input")}}
    {{form.adminPass(class="registration_form_input")}}
    {{form.confirmPass(class="registration_form_input")}}
    {{form.submit(class="registration_form_input")}}
  </form>
  <small>Possui cadastro? <a href="{{url_for('admin_login')}}">Login</a></small>
</article>
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que consegui reproduzir aqui, o problema aí é que a validação está falhando e você não está coseguindo enxergar os erros.

Você usou  `{%if form.adminName.errors%}` para verificar erros, mas só do campo `adminName`, ou seja, se não houver erros nesse campo mas houver em algum outro, você não verá esse retorno.

Para obter todos os erros, você pode usar um loop nos campos iterando sobre `form.errors.items()` e retornar apenas os erros:

```
{% for campo, erros in form.errors.items() %} 
 <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert"> # aqui você pode estilizar como quiser 
   {{ form[campo].label }} : {{''.join(erros)}}</h5>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Ao passar duas variáveis de controle, você terá acesso tanto ao campo em si quanto aos erros.

Caso prefira, você pode usar isso como uma macro:

```
{% macro mostra_erros(form) %}
{% for campo, erros in form.errors.items() %}
 <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
   {{ form[campo].label }} : {{''.join(erros)}}</h5>
 </div>
{% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

E nos templates, apenas chamá-la no lugar desejado:

```
{{ mostra_erros(form) }}
```

Espero ter ajudado e bons estudos!

Comment: Me ajudou bastante! Consegui encontrar o erro. Muito obrigado!